# Unpredictable output in Multithreading after using synchronized block of code

Tags: java, multithreading

I am calling start method on 2 thread object in which I am using a synchronized block of code in which i called a Synchronized method remove first.Still I am not getting output  randomly.My code is Following:

```
import java.util.*;
public class NameList {
    private List names =new LinkedList();

    public  synchronized void add(String name)
    {   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        names.add(name);
    }

    public synchronized String removeFirst()
    {   System.out.println(names.size());
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
        if (names.size() > 0)
        {   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
            return (String) names.remove(0);
        }
        else
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final NameList nl = new NameList();
        nl.add("Ozymandias");
        class NameDropper extends Thread {
            public void run() {
                synchronized(this)
                {   String name = nl.removeFirst();
                    System.out.println(name);
                }
            }
        }
        Thread t1 = new NameDropper();
        t1.setName("l1");
        Thread t2 = new NameDropper();
        t2.setName("l2");
        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }
}
```

I am getting different output every time.
anyone please help me to understand this multi threading behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Different output such as what? And what is the basis of your expectation that it should always be the same?

Comment: Just littering your code with `synchronized` does not make for a very good multi-threaded program.

Comment: @Rogue I don't know what you mean. There is nothing wrong with the synchronization in this code. Please make yourself clear.

Comment: What output are you getting and what output are you expecting to get?

Comment: of course you are getting a different result each time. you have a random execution order. when you start t1, it can linger around and t2 can run past it. you need some explicit serialization if you want the execution order to be determined. If you start t1 before t2 or t2 before t1 has no effect on when the threads actually enter the synchronized block inside the run method.